# how to kill a program by process name using cmd in windows 8?

Tags: windows, process, cmd, uid, taskkill

it seems that whenever i open a program in windows 8, the process name is `WWAHost.exe`

i would like to be able to do something like `TASKKILL /F /IM notepad.exe` and terminate a specific process by name

if i kill `WWAHost.exe` then all open programs will die.

any ideas?

Comment: Your question should be asked for at [Superuser](http://superuser.com/) rather than here, but `WWAHost.exe` is a safe and [essential process in Windows 8](http://www.groovypost.com/tips/wwahost-exe-windows-process-safe-running-or-virus/).

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Windows 8.1. Although WWAHost.exe is running, each application has its own process, e.g. Camera.exe or Notepad.exe. This is the case for both classical and Windows tile applications. What processes do you see when you run tasklist ?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can kill the process **and** all its children (ie. all processes started by it) using the `/t` switch:

```
taskkill /f /t /im wwahost.exe
```

---

See the documentation for [taskkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill) ([ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)) and [tskill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tskill) ([ss64](https://ss64.com/nt/tskill.html)) system utilities.

Comment: (newer) `tskill /v wwahost.exe` also works. `/v` is for verbosity (will echo the result). unlike `taskkill` it can directly accept both PID or PIN (name) as an argument to target the process with.